# disordering of elements in webpage while zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I had created home page using asp.net and have connected to live database. However, as I begin to zoom in and out and change the browser specifications the elements begin to shift on the page.

How do I stop this from happening?

[Without zoom added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX9vu.png)

[With zoom added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztleD.png)

Comment: give your divs a `width:33.33%;`

Comment: That's because your CSS is defined in pixels. Try looking into using percents to define width and height and reading about **responsive design**.